# Change attribute of an SVG shape using jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

This is my SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500">

<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="js/myscript.js"></script>

<rect id="kilote" x="70" y="70" width="50"  height="50"   style="fill:red"/>

</svg>
```

I want to change the "width" attribute of this rect from "myscript.js" file.

I have tried the following with no success (File: "myscript.js"):

```
$(function(){

$('rect[id="kilote"]').attr('width', '150');

});
```

I have tried the code here http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/21/ and it works.

However I can't make it work locally on Firefox / Chrome.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, you should start by looking at the difference between the jsfiddle version and your local one.

Comment: They are the same, the only difference is where I include the scripts <script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="js/myscript.js"></script>

Comment: Are you embedding this in an HTML file, as in the jsFiddle? Or are you trying to embed it in the SVG file? My guess is that this won't work unless you're embedding the SVG code in HTML and loading the scripts in standard HTML `script` tags.

Comment: Thanks nrabinowitz! Yor guess was right. I wrap the SVG file on an HTML and it started working. Thank you!